# Facebook credits callback routine not invoked

Tags: java, javascript, facebook-credits

When the credits `buy()` routine is called, Facebook displays this error, `There Was a Problem Processing Your Payment.` and the Payment Dialog is not displayed.

I have verified the following, but I can't find the problem:

1. Set callback url in Credits Settings: http://sharp-journey-4179.herokuapp.com/callback.jsp
2. Set myself as a Credits Tester.
3. Verified that callback routine can be reached from the Facebook Object Debugger tool.
4. Peared down callback.jsp to simply return a canned response to the payments_get_items POST.
5. Heroku router receives a POST with status 200, but the console.log output in callback.jsp is not received in Heroku logs.
6. Response to payments_get_items is:

> "{\"content\":[{\"title\":\"My app
>   \",\"description\":\"This is my app
>   .\",\"price\":2,\"product_url\":\"http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/21.png\",\"image_url\":\"http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/21.png\"}],\"method\":\"payments_get_items\"}"

The Facebook Credit documentation states that an Application Server Request is issued in response to the Buy Request.  Do I need to implement a Servlet to handle the POST and pass it to my callback routine?  How does Facebook use the name of the Callback routine, `callback.jsp`?  Does the Servlet need to be named Callback?

This is a snipit of my client `buy()` routine:

```
// The dialog only opens if you've implemented the
// Credits Callback payments_get_items.
function buy() {
  var obj = {
    method: 'pay',
    action: 'buy_item',
    // You can pass any string, but your payments_get_items must
    // be able to process and respond to this data.
    order_info: {'item_id': '1a1'},
    dev_purchase_params: {'oscif': true}
  };

  FB.ui(obj, js_callback);
}
```

This is my callback.jsp code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

console.log("In fnf callback.jsp");

//$request_type = $_POST['method'];
// Setup response.
var return_data = '';

var item = {
  title: 'My App',
  description: 'This is my app.',
  price: 2,
  product_url: 'http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/images\/gifts\/21.png',
  image_url: 'http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/images\/gifts\/21.png'
};

var content_array = new Array;
content_array[0] = item;

// Construct response.
var response = {
   content: content_array,
   method: 'payments_get_items'
};

// Response must be JSON encoded.
return_data = JSON.stringify(response);

// Send response.
alert(return_data);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to implement a Servlet to handle the credits callback POSTS received from Facebook.  I created a Servlet in my Main.java routine in the launch directory.  In Main.java, I added a context addServletMapping to send all callback POST requests to the Servlet.  The first agrument of the context.addServletMapping matches the text after the last delimeter in the Credits Callback URL entered in the Credits Settings for your app. So, the servlet does not need to be named Callback.

In summary, Facebook sends the credits callback POSTS to the callback URL via HTTP.  As a developer, you need to create a Servlet and do one of the following:

1. Map the callback POSTS to the Servlet and do the processing in the Servlet in Java.  The Credits Callback URL is a unique text string appended to your app URL.
2. Create a web.xml file where you map the Servlet to a callback.jsp file.  The Credits Callback URL is a callback.jsp file appended to the your URL.